# After adding resource to Resource file, the resource is not accessible - Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resx

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and I have .NET Core project.

I can access new added resource using `ResourceFileName.ResourceName` only if I restart the Visual Studio.

Any ideas why is that happening?!

Comment: Can you provide more info, when are you unable to access (after 1st F5), have you cleaned solution, have you tried to delete and recreate the resource file? What is the error?

Comment: I am unable to access new added resource. For example if I add new resource named `TestResource` and I try to access it `ResourceFileName.TestResource` I am getting `"ResourceFileName" does not contain definition for "TestResource" ` . The `ResourceFileName` is saved :) and I rebuild the solution. If I restart the Visual Studio then `TestResource` is accessible.

Comment: Ok that sounds like you have its `Build Action` set to **Compile** rather than **Content** or **Embedded Resource**. Can you confirm if changing this resolves the problem?

Comment: In the Properties I have only one property that says Embedded Resource. I don't have the Build Action property and I can't choose between Compile, Content or Embedded like in full Framework projects.

Comment: Adding a resource NewResouce in the Solution Explorer->Resources node does not make the resource accessible via from code via Properties.Resources.NewResouce even after restarting VS 2013. Adding it via the Resources tab of the project properties does make it accessible.